# Objective C: Coordinate of first and last point of polyline in MKMapview

Tags: objective-c, mkmapview

I followed the example below and can get all co-ordinates of a route step example:
[latitude and longitude points from MKPolyline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21861403/latitude-and-longitude-points-from-mkpolyline)
In my app I like to develop an array to calculate the first point and last point of each step.  If pointCount is the number of steps in the route, can you please suggest an updated code to get the first and last point

```
    for (int c=0; c < pointCount; c++)
    {
        NSLog(@"routeCoordinates[%d] = %f, %f", 
        c, routeCoordinates[c].latitude, 
        routeCoordinates[c].longitude);
     }
```

Comment: You need begin end of each step or the full route?

Comment: index 0 is first and index pointCount-1 is the last.